# Mostrar resultado de Formulario Contacto en DIV (HTML + PHP)

Tags: php, html

soy nuevo en esto.

Estoy diseñando una pagina, en el area de contacto logro hacer que se envie y la confirmación me muestra en una alerta y abre el index.html sin embargo; desearia se muestra en el mismo formulario en un div un mensaje ejemplo "Correo envio satisfactoriamene" o "Mensaje no enviado, intente de nuevo" y no estar recurriendo a un alert.

Este es en HTML

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col">
    <form class="contact-form" action="sendemail.php" method="POST">
        <div class="contact-form-sucess">
        <!-- MOSTRAR RESULTADO DE PHP ACA -->
        </div>
        <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-12">
            <input type="text" value="" data-msg-required="Por favor escriba su nombre." maxlength="100" class="form-control" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Nombre" required="">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-9">
            <input type="email" value="" data-msg-required="Por favor ingrese su email." data-msg-email="Please enter a valid email address." maxlength="100" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="E-mail" required="">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-3">
            <input type="integer" value="" data-msg-required="Por favor ingrese su telefono." maxlength="100" class="form-control" name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="Telefono" required="">
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col">
            <input type="text" value="" data-msg-required="Por favor ingrese un asunto." maxlength="100" class="form-control" name="subject" id="subject" placeholder="Asunto" required="">
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col">
            <textarea maxlength="5000" data-msg-required="Por favor ingrese su mensaje." rows="5" class="form-control" name="message" id="message" placeholder="Mensajes" required=""></textarea>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-row mt-2">
        <div class="form-group col">
        <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LdEGYMUAAAAAKOj1WmajjhRZRD4ZL4rZgDbWzB6"></div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-row mt-2">
        <div class="form-group col">
            <input type="submit" value="ENVIAR MENSAJE" class="btn btn-primary btn-rounded btn-4 font-weight-semibold text-0" data-loading-text="Cargando..." name="enviar">
        </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Esto es lo echo en PHP y que muestra el alert

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['enviar'])){
    //Guardamos en variables los datos enviados
    $name = utf8_decode($_POST['name']);
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $phone = utf8_decode($_POST['phone']);
    $subject = utf8_decode($_POST['subject']);
    $message = utf8_decode($_POST['message']);

    ///Validamos del lado del servidor que el nombre y el email no estén vacios
    if($name == ''){
        echo "Debe ingresar su nombre";
    }
    else if($email == ''){
        echo "Debe ingresar su email";
}else{
    $para = "etc@etccom";//Email al que se enviará
    $asunto = utf8_decode("Enviado desde Servcom-it.com");//Puedes cambiar el asunto del mensaje desde aqui
    //Este sería el cuerpo del mensaje
    $mensaje = "
        <table border='0' cellspacing='3' cellpadding='2'>
          <tr>
            <td width='30%' align='left' bgcolor='#f0efef'><strong>Nombre:</strong></td>
            <td width='80%' align='left'>$name</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td width='30%' align='left' bgcolor='#f0efef'><strong>E-mail:</strong></td>
            <td width='80%' align='left'>$email</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td width='30%' align='left' bgcolor='#f0efef'><strong>Telefono:</strong></td>
            <td width='80%' align='left'>$phone</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td width='30%' align='left' bgcolor='#f0efef'><strong>Asunto:</strong></td>
            <td width='80%' align='left'>$subject</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td width='30%' align='left' bgcolor='#f0efef'><strong>Mensaje:</strong></td>
            <td width='80%' align='left'>$message</td>       
          </tr>
    </table>    
";  

//Cabeceras del correo
    $headers = "From: $name <$email>\r\n"; //Quien envia?
    $headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP5\n";
    $headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n"; //

//Comprobamos que los datos enviados a la función MAIL de PHP estén bien y si es correcto enviamos

        //Comprobamos que los datos enviados a la función MAIL de PHP estén bien y si es correcto enviamos
    if(mail($para, $asunto, $mensaje, $headers)){
        echo "<script>alert('Gracias por escribirnos. Le responderemos en la brevedad posible.'); </script>";
        echo "<script>location.replace('index.html'); </script>";

    }else{
        echo "<script>alert('Error inesperado, intente de nuevo en unos minutos.');</script>";
        echo "<script>location.replace('index.html'); </script>";
    }
}
}   
?>
```

Si envia pero no logro hacer que aparezca el resultado en un div, e intentado varias maneras no lo logro, cual es la manera correcta en ECHO para mostrar el resultado en un div. Y aun mejor si se logra borrar el formulario + el mensaje en el div una vez enviado todo seria estupendo.

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

Aunque no es la manera más adecuada, puedes guardar la información en el array global `$_COOKIES` o en `$_SESSION`, también puedes cambiar ese alert por un `localStorage.setItem()` para que luego lo obtengas y lo muestres.  Contáctame si deseas ayuda.

Comment: la ayuda es aqui, para eso estas usando la zona de respuestas

Comment: Hola, gracias por la respuesta. Bueno en si de PHP no se casi nada lo poco que se es para pequeños formularios. Si me ayudas con un ejemplo por favor.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que ***quieres es permanecer en la página de contacto y mostrar un mensaje de "feedback" al usuario, ya sea de confirmación del envío o de error del mismo***, ¿correcto?

Reemplaza el siguiente código:

```
//Comprobamos que los datos enviados a la función MAIL de PHP estén bien y si es correcto enviamos
if(mail($para, $asunto, $mensaje, $headers)){
    echo "<script>alert('Gracias por escribirnos. Le responderemos en la brevedad posible.'); </script>";
    echo "<script>location.replace('index.html'); </script>";

}else{
    echo "<script>alert('Error inesperado, intente de nuevo en unos minutos.');</script>";
    echo "<script>location.replace('index.html'); </script>";
}
```

Con el último script estas redireccionando al index y dices que no quieres que cambie la página, este código sobra.

Para los mensajes, puedes implementar un sistema de feedbacks si consideras que los vas a usar en más páginas que sería lo habitual. Lo normal es usar dos tipos de feedbacks: uno para las acciones realizadas correctamente (normalmente en verde) y otro para los mensajes de error (normalmente en rojo). De una u otra forma suele usarse la global $_SESSION para almacenarlos y se borran después de mostrarlos.

**La forma más sencilla de hacer lo que necesitas, que sólo permite almacenar / mostrar un sólo mensaje de feedback de cada tipo** es:

***1. Guardar el mensaje cuando se produzca algo que deba ser comunicado al usuario***, por ejemplo un error:

```
$_SESSION['error'] = 'Error enviando mensaje de contacto.';
```

***2. Comprobar si hay mensajes positivos o negativos que mostrar al usuario, mostrarlos en la página en caso afirmativo y eliminarlos de sesión seguidamente.***

```
if (isset($_SESSION['error']) && $_SESSION['error']) {

    echo '<div class="feedback error-feedback">';
    echo '<p>' . $_SESSION['error'] . '</p>';
    echo '</div>';

    // aquí eliminas el mensaje que acabas de mostrar de la sesión
    unset($_SESSION['error']);
}

if (isset($_SESSION['ok']) && $_SESSION['ok']) {

    echo '<div class="feedback ok-feedback">';
    echo '<p>' . $_SESSION['ok'] . '</p>';
    echo '</div>';

    // aquí eliminas el mensaje que acabas de mostrar de la sesión
    unset($_SESSION['ok']);
}
```

y por supuesto ***queda aplicar unos estilos CSS adecuados a tus mensajes***, por ejemplo:

```
.feedback {
    background   : #a7f2ac; /* lightgreen */
    border       : 1px solid green;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color        : green;
    margin       : 5%;
    padding      : 3%;
}

.error-feedback {
    background  : #f79696; /* lightred */
    border-color: red;
    color       : red;
}
```

Comment: Hola gracias, pero para llamar a ese resultado en el div? la pagina de contacto es .html

Comment: @xebeac si estas usando PHP para generar las páginas del sitio lo normal es que tus páginas sean .php, todo el código que no este entre las etiquetas de apertura y cierre de PHP no pasará por el intérprete de PHP. Si quieres separar completamente la parte *front* del backend, lo normal sería usar llamadas ajax, websockets, implementar un api-rest, o algo similar. En ese caso puedes almacenar los mensajes de respuesta en variables JavaScript y usar también este lenguaje para cambiar el DOM y mostrar los feedbacks.

Comment: muy bien explicado la idea de lo que quieres hacer... pero como se implementa en el codigo inicial que tiene el muchacho? Gracias de antemano. Saludos.